# how to evaluate a derivative of a function in matlab in one point? Error "dimensions must agree"

Tags: matlab

I have a function called `funcion(x)` which does:

```
function fx = funcion(x)
    fx = cos(x);  %%  
    return;
```

then in my other function (they are both in the same script) called `newtonRaph` i'm doing this:

```
function raiz = newtonRaph(xi,imax, tol)
    syms x;
    iter = 0;
    xold = xi;
    x = xold;
    df = diff(cos(x),x);  
    er = 0.9;
    while (er>tol)&&(iter<imax)
        dfr = (subs(df,x,xold)); 
        nuevo = 0.222/dfr;
        if(dfr ==0) 
          disp('dfr was 0...');
          break;
        else
          iter = iter+1;
          evaluacion = funcion(x);
          xnew = xold - (evaluacion/dfr); %Newton-Raphson formula
             if(xnew~=0)&& (iter>1)
               er = abs((xnew-xold)/xnew); %
             end
          xold = xnew;
          x =  xold; 
        end
    end

root = xnew;
```

As you can see, i added a test line that does `new = 0.222/dfr` just to try and see what's happening with the derivative.
I don't know what is it that i'm doing wrong, but every time i run this, it tells me

```
??? Error using ==> mldivide
Matrix dimensions must agree.

Error in ==> newtonRaph at 16
    nuevo = 0.222/dfr;
```

I would be really thankful if anyone could tell me what to do.

Comment: Are you looking for [element-wise division (dot-divide)](http://www.mathworks.com/help/fixedpoint/ref/rdivide.html)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If `dfr` is not a scalar, and you only want to divide `0.222` by all the elements in it, then you should write `nuevo = 0.222./dfr` with a `.` before the `/`.